# Django cut queries to get only "nth to nth" results

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I'm coding a multi page table view using in `Javascript using AJAX/Jquery`, the database has a lot of records so every time user changes page a new query will be asked from the served and only those showed will be sent

So let's say user clicks page 5 and has chose to display 15 results per page, the view should query the results but only send from the (5*15)nth to the (6*15)nth objects.

1) How exactly can you cut a `QuerySet` as described above?

2) Is there a way to include this in the `Query` itself for better performance? Or do I need to first call `MyModel.objects.all()` and then cut the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django ORM respects common python list manipulation patterns, when you use
`MyModel.objects.all()`, the original query is excecuted/performed only when it is consumed.Lets See,

```
MyModel.objects.all()[10:20]
```

Here internally python `slice` dunder methods are working in a way that it performs with LIMIT & OFFSET query instead of processing in memory.

**Recommended Solution to the Problem**

Use django pagination for your purpose, you can check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view) for more details.

```
my_list = MyModel.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(my_list, 15) # 15 objects per page
```

Comment: Ah, I might have misunderstood how it works then, so If I `x = MyModel.objects.all()` in one line, and in the next line `x = x.filter(pk=1)` , only when I call filter will a query be executed?

Comment: yes, django queries are lazy, but beware when using like x = list(MyModel.obejcts.all()), here query will be performed

Answer (score 2):

You can slice a query with the normal Python slicing:

```
MyModel.objects.all()[10:20]
```

For details see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

You should also read this section of the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/

Comment: So there isn't a way to limit it in the query call right? I have to first get all the objects and then slice them

Comment: No, the slicing is modifying the query with a `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. Which BTW is written in the docs I linked.